# how to add constant value to a comma separated list in awk

Tags: awk, addition

I have file with sample tow shown below:

```
col1     col2      col3    col4   col5                    col6
247828  313574  55,126,184  25  4734,163,133,81,130   0,6637,8368,9333,14005
```

I would need to add the value in col1 to each element in col6 so that output looks like:

```
col1     col2      col3    col4   col5                    col6
247828  313574  55,126,184  25  4734,163,133,81,130   247828,254465,256196,257161,261833
```

I tried using

```
awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{array[arraylen++]=$6;for (i =0; i < arraylen; i++) print array[i];  }1'
```

I guess i m lost somewhere and it prints the 6 elements in col6. Could someone help to work through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {
        split($6,a,/,/)
        new=""
        for (i=1;i in a;i++) {
            new = new (i>1?",":"") a[i]+$1
        }
        sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,new)
    } 1' file
col1     col2      col3    col4   col5                    col6
247828  313574  55,126,184  25  4734,163,133,81,130   247828,254465,256196,257161,261833
```

Note that the above will retain whatever white space you originally had between fields in your input file.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for something like this:

```
$ cat file
247828  313574  55,126,184      25      4734,163,133,81,130     0,6637,8368,9333,14005
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ n = split($6, a, ","); 
    s = ""; 
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) s = s a[i]+$1 (i<n?",":"");
    $6 = s;
} 1' file 
247828  313574  55,126,184      25      4734,163,133,81,130     247828,254465,256196,257161,261833
```

Set the Output Field Separator to the tab character (the input one doesn't need changing from the default). Split the 6th field into the array `a`. Loop through the array to build up the new value of the 6th field.

As suggested in the comments (thanks), rather than assigning to `$6` repeatedly, I have used a temporary variable `s`. This means that the record is only written to once, which is better for performance.

Comment: I'm sure you know that wil change the white space between fields if they aren't already tabs but additionally think about the performance - awk will recompile the current record every time you assign a value to `$6` so it'll do that 6 times for every record with 5 values in $6 like in the current sample input. That will probably have a noticeable impact if the file is large vs assigning to a variable and then doing `$6=var` at the end so the record's only recompiled once.

Comment: I assumed that the fields in the input were separated by tabs, since the OP set `FS` to the tab character in the question. Fair point about the performance though, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, though it's always a bit of a gamble trying to guess what a script should do from reading a script that doesn't do it :-). In particular - the posted input file doesn't have the starting points of the columns on every line left-aligned with each other and just looking at the amount of separation between them there'd certainly be more than 1 tab between "col5" and "col6" on the first line so it doesn't look like a tab-separated file to me but idk.

Comment: sorry for the messed up input file. It is a tab-delimited file.